# Xcode warning: xcshareddata missing file (after delete a 3rd party library via CocoaPods)

Tags: xcode, workspace

I use Versions as version control, and CocoaPods as library control. After I deleted a library source path in the **podfile**, deleted the .xcworkspace file and run `pod install` under **Terminal.app**, the library was removed and the .xcworkspace file was re-created. But the Xcode compiler reports a warning: *xcshareddate is missing from working copy*.

How could I solve this warning?

Answer (score 1):

The `xcshareddata` directory is primarily used to store shared settings (as opposed to `xcuserdata` which is used for settings which are not shared a.k.a. user specific). It is managed in XCode with the "Scheme manager" which can be accessed via the "Product" > "Scheme" > "Manage Schemes" menu items. Opening the Scheme manager and removing / recreating any shared schemes should correct the warning.